# Subclassing a dynamically loaded class in Java

Tags: java, reflection

Assume I obtained a `Class` object by loading a class dynamically using `Class.forName("Foo")`. `Foo` is abstract in this case, so I cannot call `newInstance()` on it. (How) is it possible to declare a concrete subclass of `Foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare it as not abstract e.g.

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    // implement methods are required.
}
```

In short, just because you loaded the class dynamically doesn't mean the rules change ;)

> Foo is not available at compile-time

If you don't have Foo available at compile time, you still need to have a sub-class of this class which is concrete to create it.  To do this you have two options.

- find a concrete class and create that.  You can use the [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library to find such a class.
- generate code and compile it using the Compiler API, or BeanShell.
- generate byte code for the subclass using ObjectWeb's ASM.

I suspect the first option is what you need because unless there is a subclass provided for you, you still need to generate the code for the abstract methods.

Comment: `Foo` is not available at compile-time, so I cannot write the above code. The compiler complains: "cannot find symbol: class Foo".

Comment: @badweather, It is only a example. You must declare `Foo` class first.

Comment: @badweather I have added detail based on your comment.

Comment: @Peter, thanks for the detailed answer. I know for sure that there exists no concrete subclass of `Foo`. So I suspect I'll have to generate code.